# How do I add a powershell item to an array?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

My goal is to use the output of the following command in an `export-csv` command.

Code:

```
$all 

Foreach($mbx In Get-Mailbox)
 {
    $tmp=   [PSCustomObject]@{Name= $mbx; Company=$(Get-User $_).Company; ActiveSyncEnabled=$(Get-CASMailbox $_).ActiveSyncEnabled} 
    $all = $all + $tmp
}
```

When I run the code above, I get the following error:

```
Bad argument to operator '+': Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Name'  Key being added: 'Name'.
At line:4 char:18
+     $all = $all + <<<<  $tmp
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadOperatorArgument
```

**Question**

How do I correctly create the new powershell object, or add it to an array, so that I can send the output to a different commandlet?

Comment: That '$all' before the loop is not doing anything for you; you did not define it as an array. Have you tried @mjolinor's code?

Answer (score 1):

[PSObject] isn't a valid type accelerator.

Corrected script:

```
 $all =
 Foreach($_ In Get-Mailbox | select -first 10)
  {
   New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name= $_.Name; Company=$(Get-User $_.DistinguishedName).Company; ActiveSyncEnabled=$(Get-CASMailbox $_.Name).ActiveSyncEnabled} 
 }

 $all | 
 select Name,Company,ActiveSyncEnabled |
 Export-Csv c:\somedir\mailboxinfo.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: type accelerator is a concept foreign to me... I'll have to look it up

Comment: I just made the change, and get an identical error returned.

Comment: Seems like the CSV contains weird data: `"False","False","False","System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection","System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection","System.Object","3"`

Comment: What version of Powershell are you using?

Comment: $PSVersionTable.PSVersion = 2.0. -1 -1

Answer (score 1):

I suggest replacing the variable you call $_ with something like $mailbox.

Comment: Same error: `
Bad argument to operator '+': Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Name'  Key being added: 'Name'.`

Comment: That wasn't the original exception you posted though.

Comment: You're correct; I corrected it soon after posting.  The wrong error was in the clipboard.

Comment: Gotcha, I'm a lil bit offside now though, gotta reboot brain. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The following command adds custom items to an array

```
 $array = @()

Foreach($_ In Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited )
 {
    $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $object | Add-Member -Name 'Name' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $_.Name
    $object | Add-Member -Name 'Company' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value (Get-User $_.DistinguishedName).Company
    $object | Add-Member -Name 'ActiveSyncEnabled' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value (Get-CASMailbox $_.Name).ActiveSyncEnabled
   $array += $object 
}


$array | Export-Csv c:\somedir\mailboxinfo.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the ForEach in a subexpression.

```
$(
Foreach($_ In Get-Mailbox | select -first 10)
 {
   [PSCustomObject]@{Name= $_.Name; Company=$(Get-User $_.DistinguishedName).Company; ActiveSyncEnabled=$(Get-CASMailbox $_.Name).ActiveSyncEnabled} 

}) | Export-Csv c:\somedir\mailboxinfo.csv -NoTypeInformation
```